# How do I persist an item being favorited using React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to use React event listeners to favorite a bookmark item & change the value of the favorite attribute from null to "true".

Here is my bookmarkCard.js component file:

```js
const handleFavorite = () => {
        props.favoriteBookmark(props.id)
        history.push('/bookmarks')
    }
```

```js
 <div className="bookmark-card" id={`bookmark-${props.id}`}>
            <h2 className="bookmark-headline">{props.headline}</h2>
                <p className="bookmark-description">{props.description}</p>
                <Link to='#' className="bookmark-web-url" onClick={() => openInNewTab("http://" + `${props.web_url}`)}>{props.web_url}</Link>
                <Button 
                    id={props.id}
                    onClick={handleFavorite}
                    className="favorite-button" 
                    startIcon={<FavoriteIcon/>}>
                </Button><br></br>
```

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      deleteBookmark: (id) => dispatch(deleteBookmark(id)),
      favoriteBookmark: (id) => dispatch(favoriteBookmark(id))
    }
}
  
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BookmarkCard)
```

Here is my favoriteBookmark action creator:

```js
export function favoriteBookmark(id, favorite){
        return(dispatch, getState) => {
            const bookmark = getState().bookmarks.bookmarks.find(bookmark => bookmark.id === id)
            const data = {
                headline: bookmark.headline,
                web_url: bookmark.web_url,
                description: bookmark.description,
                id: id, 
                favorite: favorite
            }
            const configObject = {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accepts: 'application/json',
                
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/${id}`, configObject)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                   response.json().then(json => {
                        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                        dispatch({type: FAVORITE_BOOKMARK, payload: json})
                   })
                } else {
                    console.log(response)
                    return response.json().then((json) => {
                        return Promise.reject(json)
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch({type: ERROR, payload: error})
            })
        }
}
```

Here is my favorite bookmark reducer:

```js
case FAVORITE_BOOKMARK:
            return state.bookmarks.map(bookmark => {
                if (bookmark.id !== action.payload.toString()){
                    return bookmark
                }
                return {
                    ...bookmark,
                    favorite: !bookmark.favorite
                }
            })
```

Once I click the favorite button, the button is focused but upon page refresh it is unclicked.

Here is my app.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../App.css'

import Navbar from './Navbar'
import FilterCategory from '../containers/FilterCategory'
import Bookmarks from '../containers/Bookmarks'
import AboutUs from '../containers/AboutUs'
import Categories from '../containers/Categories'
import Home from '../containers/Home'
import BookmarkCard from '../containers/BookmarkCard'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import history from '../history'

import { getBookmarks, createBookmark, deleteBookmark, favoriteBookmark, filterCategory} from '../actions/index'
import { getCategories, createCategory, deleteCategory } from '../actions/index'





class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getBookmarks()
    this.props.getCategories()
  }
  
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router history={history}>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Home />}/>
              <Route exact path='/about' render={() => <AboutUs/>} />
              <Route exact path="/bookmarks" render={routeProps => <Bookmarks bookmarks={this.props.bookmarks} getBookmarks={this.props.getBookmarks} createBookmark={this.props.createBookmark} filterCategory={this.props.filterCategory} deleteBookmark={this.props.deleteBookmark} favoriteBookmark={this.props.favoriteBookmark} categories={this.props.categories} createCategory={this.props.createCategory} {...routeProps} />}/>
              <Route exact path="/categories" render={routeProps => <Categories categories={this.props.categories} deleteCategory={this.props.deleteCategory} {...routeProps} /> }/>
              <Route exact path='/bookmarks/:id' render={routeProps => <BookmarkCard categories={this.props.categories} deleteBookmark={this.props.deleteBookmark} favoriteBookmark={this.props.favoriteBookmark} {...routeProps}/>}/>
              <Route exact path='/categories/:id' render={routeProps => <FilterCategory categories={this.props.categories} bookmarks={this.props.bookmarks} deleteBookmark={this.props.deleteBookmark} favoriteBookmark={this.props.favoriteBookmark} {...routeProps}/>}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    bookmarks: state.bookmarks.bookmarks,
    categories: state.categories.categories,
    requesting: state.requesting
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createBookmark: (bookmark) => dispatch(createBookmark(bookmark)),
    deleteBookmark: (id) => dispatch(deleteBookmark(id)),
    getBookmarks: () => dispatch(getBookmarks()),
    favoriteBookmark: (id, favorite) => dispatch(favoriteBookmark(id, favorite)),
    createCategory: (category) => dispatch(createCategory(category)),
    deleteCategory: (id) => dispatch(deleteCategory(id)),
    getCategories: () => dispatch(getCategories()),
    filterCategory: (id) => dispatch(filterCategory(id))
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

And here is my index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'


const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider >,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Please also share your app.js file where you have added redux wrapper or consumer to your app. Have you used any `PersistGate`?

Comment: @bonnopc Edited my question and added both my app.js + index.js . I am trying to not use PersistGate

Comment: You will need to use some form of persistence either on your server or using a client side offering like localStorage or IndexDB